# Activate-Feature : Error activating feature <featurename> at siteURl>The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

```
Error:
Activate-Feature : Error activating feature …<featurename>……… at …<siteURl>……..The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Issue has caused when using PowerShell script to retract and deploy WSP solution, WSP deploys successfully but somehow it get failed to activate a feature with event receiver
I am starting the services as below:

```
Stop-Service -Name “SPAdminV4”
Start-SPAdminJob
Start-Service -Name SPAdminV4
WaitForSolutionDeploymentJobToFinish $name
```

*Note:* I have not found any issue when I do fresh deployment instead retraction/deployment.
I even it works file when I retract the solution in separate script and do deployment with new powershell instance

I have found following references while investigating:
http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/getting-around-gac-problems-when-you-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-with-powershell/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2011/02/17/sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-solution-deploy-deployment.aspx

Please guide me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have come by this a few times. Unfortunately I have not the time to dive into it further but an application pool recycle seems to fix the issue for me.

Comment: i have tried to forcefully restart IIS from Powershell script but that didn't help me... So i have foudn a work around i have started a new process from current powershell session and carrid out rest of the steps from there. it resolved the issue:                                 Write-Host "Starting new process"
  Start-Sleep 5
  Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoExit','& S:\powersellscript.ps1'
  Stop-Process -Id $PID

Comment: App pool recycle on Central Admin App Pool?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to forcefully restart IIS from Powershell script but that didn't help me... So i have found a workaround i have started a new process from current powershell session and carried out rest of the steps from there. it resolved the issue:

Write-Host "Starting new process" 
Start-Sleep 5 Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoExit','& S:\powersellscript.ps1'
Stop-Process -Id $PID

Comment: param (
   
   [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})] 
   [string]
   $argument1Configurationfilename,
   [int]
   $argument1 
   [int]
   $argument2"= 99
)
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$scriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$config = [xml](Get-Content -Read -1 (Join-Path $scriptDir $configFileName))
  Write-Host "Starting new process"
  Start-Sleep 2
  #new powershell process
  Start-Process powershell.exe "$($scriptDir)\powershellscript.ps1 argument1 argument2"
  #close powershell process
  Stop-Process -Id $PID

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen Visual Studio solve the problem to me.